# Go: How do I turn response body into request body?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, go

I have a handler that makes a request to elasticsearch.
I cat get the json response from that request:

```
resp, err := http.Get(getUrl)
defer resp.Body.Close()
bodyString := ""
if resp.StatusCode == 200{
    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) 
    checkForError(err)
       bodyString = string(bodyBytes)

       fmt.Fprintf(w, bodyString)
}
```

How do I turn that `bodyString` into something I can pass to an http.Post of this sort:

```
http.Post("https://httpbin.org/post", "application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonData)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really sure what are you trying to achive, but may be it help.

```
bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
reader := bytes.NewReader(bodyBytes)
http.Post("https://httpbin.org/post", "application/json; charset=utf-8", reader)

//or you can do it directly
//http.Post("https://httpbin.org/post", "application/json; charset=utf-8", resp.Body)
```